# Data validation using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to create a data validation using appscript.
The aim here is to check the value of 2 different cells then put a validation on a 3rd cell.

Say If **C3=Office** and **D3=Retail** then a data validation should be applied on cell **F3** where the user can only put the numbers between **50-100**.

This code works if I only use 1 cell like **C3** but doesn't do anything if I also add **D3**.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

```
function onEdit() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('final rough');
 var cell2 = sheet.getRange("C3");
 var cell3 = sheet.getRange("D3");
 var cell4 = sheet.getRange("F3");
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
 .requireNumberBetween(50, 100)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();


 if(cell2 == "Office" && cell3 == "Retail"){
   cell4.setDataValidation(rule);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're checking the actual values of the cells:

```js
function onEdit() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('final rough');
 var cell2 = sheet.getRange("C3").getValue(); //<< Get the values
 var cell3 = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue(); //<< of these cells
 var cell4 = sheet.getRange("F3");
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
 .requireNumberBetween(50, 100)
 .setAllowInvalid(false)
 .build();


 if(cell2 == "Office" && cell3 == "Retail"){
   cell4.setDataValidation(rule);
 }
 }
```

Comment: I did, C3 = Office and D3 = Retail.

Comment: @Sid Look at my code and make sure you notice the code I added where you define `cell2` and `cell3`. You need to use the `.getValue()` method on these cells in order to compare their values to a string in your `if()` statement.